# Enable unrar to read foo.partn.rar AND foo.partn.rar.part

Tags: rar

I'm using the standard UNRAR 3.90 beta 2 freeware from ubuntu lucid 10.04.

When downloading (using jdownloader or firefox) the chunks that make up a rar archive, the files sometimes have an additional extension `.part` to indicate that they're not yet fully downloaded, i.e.

- `foo.part1.rar`      [fully downloaded]
- `foo.part2.rar.part` [partially downloaded]

When executing `unrar foo.part1.rar`, unrar doesn't find `foo.part2.rar.part` because of the additional `.part` suffix. Is there any option that would allow it to do so?

Comment: Why would you want to open a **partly** downloaded rar archive (which would most likely seem broken to the unpacker anyway)?!

Comment: @Ignacio: unrar foo.part1.rar foo.part2.rar.part doesn't apparently work. Is there a way of specifying the complete list of archive chunks to use rather than unrar detecting them automatically from the stem of the first part?

Comment: @Bobby: with the -kb option, you can unrar a partial download to inspect some of the contents without waiting for all archive chunks to download. This is highly useful given that the complete download may take several hours.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that such an option exists.

Answer (score 0):

A crude workaround would be to copy the downloaded & yet-to-be-fully-downloaded files to another directory and rename the partially downloaded one.